# how to identify time overlap in r

Tags: r, date, overlap

I have a dataframe (df) with admission and discharge dates of patients, with 4 columns:

> ID,  admitDate (as date),  dcDate (as date), los (length of stay in
>   days).

```
$ admitDate  : Date, format: "2009-09-19" "2010-01-24" "2010-09-30" ...
$ dcDate     : Date, format: "2009-09-23" "2010-01-27" "2010-10-04" ...
$ los        : num  4 3 4 25 6 3 6 2 2 3 ...
```

I need to be able to tell at any given time how many patients (and which patients) were admitted. That is, I think I need to find out the overlap between the patients' los. Here is how I'm defining overlap: (df$admitDate[x] <= df$disDate[y]) & (df$admitDate[y] <= df$disDate[x])

Any help is much appreciated.

Here is the output of dput for the first 20 patients:

```
> dput(head(df,20))
structure(list(Unit.Number = c(2013459L, 2013459L, 2047815L, 
1362858L, 1331174L, 2068040L, 1363711L, 2175972L, 2036695L, 1426614L, 
1403126L, 2083126L, 1334063L, 1349385L, 1404482L, 2175545L, 1296600L, 
1293220L, 1336768L, 2148401L), admitDate = structure(c(14506, 
14633, 14882, 15172, 14945, 15632, 15482, 15601, 16096, 15843, 
16013, 15548, 15436, 15605, 16115, 15597, 15111, 15050, 15500, 
15896), class = "Date"), dcDate = structure(c(14510, 14636, 14886, 
15197, 14951, 15635, 15488, 15603, 16098, 15846, 16016, 15552, 
15438, 15606, 16118, 15598, 15113, 15058, 15501, 15915), class = "Date"), 
los = c(4, 3, 4, 25, 6, 3, 6, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 1, 
2, 8, 1, 19)), .Names = c("Unit.Number", "admitDate", "dcDate", 
"los"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

First, I tried the code suggested by  G. Grothendieck:

```
days <- seq(min(df$admitDate), max(df$dcDate), "day")
no.patients <- data.frame(
  Date = days, 
  Num = sapply(days, function(d) sum(d >= df$admitDate & d <= df$dcDate)),
  Patients = sapply(days, function(d)
        toString(df$Unit.Number[d >= df$admitDate & d <= df$dcDate]))
)
```

And here is what happened:

```
> days <- seq(min(df$admitDate), max(df$dcDate), "day")
Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : 'to' cannot be NA, NaN or infinite
> no.patients <- data.frame(Date = d, 
+                           Num = sapply(days, function(d) sum(d >= df$admitDate & d <=         df$dcDate)))
Error in data.frame(Date = d, Num = sapply(days, function(d) sum(d >=  : 
object 'd' not found
```

Then, I thought maybe I need to get rid of NA's. So here is what I did:

```
> df <- df[rowSums(is.na(df)) < 0, ]
```

And tried again. Here is what I got:

```
> days <- seq(min(df$admitDate), max(df$dcDate), "day")
Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : 'to' cannot be NA, NaN or infinite
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min.default(numeric(0), na.rm = FALSE) :
no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max.default(numeric(0), na.rm = FALSE) :
no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
> no.patients <- data.frame(Date = d, 
+                           Num = sapply(days, function(d) sum(d >= df$admitDate & d <=   df$dcDate)))
Error in data.frame(Date = d, Num = sapply(days, function(d) sum(d >=  : 
object 'd' not found
```

Comment: Please display enough data using `dput` to use as an example.

Comment: when I try to cut and paste from df, it looks unintelligible, everything follows each other, not in rows and columns. As you can tell, I'm pretty novice in all of this.

Comment: The purpose of `dput` is so that those who answer can simply copy your output and paste it back into their session to exactly reproduce it.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks for advice. I've added the dput for the first 20 patients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another way.  This is a process that will create the size of the queue based on entry/exit times and can be used in this case to compute the number of patients:

```
df <- structure(list(Unit.Number = c(2013459L, 2013459L, 2047815L, 
1362858L, 1331174L, 2068040L, 1363711L, 2175972L, 2036695L, 1426614L, 
1403126L, 2083126L, 1334063L, 1349385L, 1404482L, 2175545L, 1296600L, 
1293220L, 1336768L, 2148401L), admitDate = structure(c(14506, 
14633, 14882, 15172, 14945, 15632, 15482, 15601, 16096, 15843, 
16013, 15548, 15436, 15605, 16115, 15597, 15111, 15050, 15500, 
15896), class = "Date"), dcDate = structure(c(14510, 14636, 14886, 
15197, 14951, 15635, 15488, 15603, 16098, 15846, 16016, 15552, 
15438, 15606, 16118, 15598, 15113, 15058, 15501, 15915), class = "Date"), 
los = c(4, 3, 4, 25, 6, 3, 6, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 1, 
2, 8, 1, 19)), .Names = c("Unit.Number", "admitDate", "dcDate", 
"los"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")

# create dataframe for computing the size of the queue (concurrent patients)
x <- data.frame(date = c(df$admitDate, df$dcDate)
            , op = c(rep(1, nrow(df)), rep(-1, nrow(df)))
            , Unit.Number = c(df$Unit.Number, df$Unit.Number)
            )
# sort and calculate concurrent patients
x <- x[order(x$date), ]  # sort in time order
x$cum <- cumsum(x$op)

# 'x' will have the 'cum' equal to the number of patients concurrently.
# for 'op' == 1, you have the patient ID and 'cum' will be the number of
# patients at that time.

plot(x$date, x$cum, type = 's')
```

This is what the first part of 'x' looks like:

```
> head(x,10)
         date op Unit.Number cum
1  2009-09-19  1     2013459   1
21 2009-09-23 -1     2013459   0
2  2010-01-24  1     2013459   1
22 2010-01-27 -1     2013459   0
3  2010-09-30  1     2047815   1
23 2010-10-04 -1     2047815   0
5  2010-12-02  1     1331174   1
25 2010-12-08 -1     1331174   0
18 2011-03-17  1     1293220   1
38 2011-03-25 -1     1293220   0
>
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. Many thanks. Now I'm going to study the codes, hopefully to understand and learn from it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
days <- seq(min(df$admitDate), max(df$dcDate), "day")
no.patients <- data.frame(
      Date = days, 
      Num = sapply(days, function(d) sum(d >= df$admitDate & d <= df$dcDate)),
      Patients = sapply(days, function(d)
            toString(df$Unit.Number[d >= df$admitDate & d <= df$dcDate]))
)
```

giving:

```
> head(no.patients)
        Date Num Patients
1 2009-09-19   1  2013459
2 2009-09-20   1  2013459
3 2009-09-21   1  2013459
4 2009-09-22   1  2013459
5 2009-09-23   1  2013459
6 2009-09-24   0
```

**ADDED** patient list to each row.  Fixed case of `df`.

Comment: I've tried it. See above (the original question) to read the error messages I got.

Comment: I had updated the answer at one point and I think you grabbed it before my revisions.  I have added the first few lines of output to show that it does work on the sample data provided.  If you still get errors then you will need to provide a reproducible example that shows them.

Comment: After removing NA's, it works perfectly fine and the result -plot(no.patient$Date, no.patient$Num) - is identical to the suggestion made bellow. Many tx.